# Configuring CMake to build with Xcode

Tags: xcode4, cmake

I am involved in development of a large cross platform project that build for Windows, Linux, and Mac OS X. The build for the software is configured with CMake.

The CMake scripts have been designed to configure successfully for Visual Studio on Windows, and Makefiles are currently used for building on Linux and Mac OS X.

Pretty much all of the development for the project so far has been done with people working on Windows, and a little bit of work on Linux. I am interested in developing for the project using Xcode 4.6 on a Macintosh running Mac OS X 10.7, and I have encountering problems as the CMake files do not seem to configure properly for that development environment.

For non-windows platforms many custom commands have been written to try to configure things such as copying needed files or setting environments that are needed for certain operations such as running unit tests during the build process.

It seems that because Xcode is an integrated development environment simliar to Visual Studio is has this concept of a build configuration, and when software gets build output files in up in a directory path that includes that configuration concept (i.e. many build files end up in a path that ends with folder named something like Debug, Release, etc.)

CMake is supposed to have support for dealing with this build configuration concept and the mechanism utilized work well for Visual Studio. That do no seem to work for Xcode. For example our build engineers have design CMake scripts so that for Windows, many path and whatnot are configured using the CMAKE_CFG_INTDIR value which helps to qualify the build configuration.

The use of CMAKE_CFG_INTDIR is not working for Xcode as the script for Macintosh were written with Makefiles in mind which don't really have the build configuration concept. The use of CMAKE_CFG_INTDIR within custom commands used to configure things fails on the Macintosh as the value resolves to $(CONFIGURATION)$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME). This values are not define when the custom commands are run, so values are not set properly and build operations fail.

It is unclear what is needed so that the system can successfully configure for Xcode. Searching on the Internet so far has not yielded insight into what should be used to make sure that build configuration can be successful. What resources are available that would help in figuring out how to configure this project to build with Xcode?

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about custom commands set using [`add_custom_command`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3aadd_custom_command), then you should prefer "generator expressions" to avoid issues regarding per-configuration build directories.  From the docs for `add_custom_command`:

> Arguments to `COMMAND` may use "generator expressions" with the syntax "`$<...>`". Generator expressions are evaluated during build system generation to produce information specific to each build configuration.

For example, the build directory for a target called "MyExe" could be referred to as `$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:MyExe>`

Generator expressions are available in a few CMake commands, not just `add_custom_command`.

If you have more specific problems, it's maybe worth asking further question(s) with the relevant details.